# The graph polynomial of the Total Graph of a Graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials, graph-colorings

Consider the [Total Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalGraph.html) ($T(G)$) of a graph $G$ with vertex set $V$ edge set $E=\{(u,v)\}$ with Line graph $L(G)$ and subdivision graph $S(G)$ (formed by putting a vertex in each edge of the original graph). Consider the graph polynomial $P_G=\prod_{(u,v)\in E}(u-v)$ of the graph $G$.

Then, it is easy to see that $P_{T(G)}=P_{G}\cdot P_{L(G)}\cdot P_{S(G)}$.

Can we use the this polynomial to verify the Total coloring conjecture by establishing that the polynomial $P_T(G)$ does not lie in the ideal generated by the polynomials $u^{\Delta+2}-1\ \ ,u\in V\ \ $? Specifically, since the polynomials $P_G$ and $P_{L(G)}$ already do not lie individually in the ideals generated by $u^  {\Delta+2}-1$, thanks to Brooks and Vizings' theorems; and the graph $P(S(G))$, being the polynomial of a bipartite graph, elementarily satisfies the condition. This, coupled with the fact the polynomial ring is an integral domain and the ideal generated by the polynomials $u^{\Delta+2}-1\ \ ,u\in V\ \ $ is a prime ideal (I think) should give us the desired result, right? Are there any overlooked facts here? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The ideal you've defined is not prime since $x^n-1$ is reducible whenever $n>1$.

Comment: @GabeConant yes, i thought about that, for if it were prime, then just $\Delta+1$ colors would have sufficed, which is clearly false. So we have to reduce $P$ using a suitable grobner basis